# asp.net template engine

Tags: asp.net, templates

I'm building a website. It allows the user to edit their website template, so I need a template engine for asp.net web form (I'm using C#). I'm worry about security problem, about user can write some c# code. So any template engine recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://ndjango.org - which is based from Django template - it supports almost all Django template functionality.

http://www.stringtemplate.org/ is also useful although it is very very strict.

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure but perhaps DotNetNuke can be used. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/